# Integrability: Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

This thread is related to: [Spectral Measure: Dominated Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1058310/79762)

Given a measure space $\Omega$.

Consider a sequence of square integrables: $\int|f_n|^2\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$

Suppose pointwise convergence: $f_n\to f$.

Does the following hold:
$$\int|f_m-f_n|^2\mathrm{d}\mu\to0\implies\int|f-f_n|^2\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$

The problem is that they may have no dominant at all:
$$s_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\chi_{(n,n+1]}\to0:\quad\int|s_m-s_n|^2\mathrm{d}\mu\stackrel{m\neq n}{=}\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\to0\quad\int\sup_n|s_n|\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Comment: Are the $f_n$ individually square integrable?  What sort of convergence is your arrow indicating?  What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is not clear what "an approximation $f_n\to f$" means. Does the sequence converge pointwise? Almost everywhere? Uniformly? In $L^2$?

Comment: @JasonKnapp: Pointwise convergence of square integrable functions. Will add these details. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ok, I got it now: Fatou! :D*

Extracting the step within the completeness proofs:
$$\int\|F-F_n\|^2\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\liminf\int\|F_m-F_n\|^2\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$
*(Note that this works perfectly for Banach spaces!)*

Answer (score 1):

See for a related question [Does $L^p$ convergence imply pointwise convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere).

Since you have $(f_n)$ converging to some function $y$ in $L^2$, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converging to $y$ a.e., and therefore since this subsequence also converges pointwise to $f$ we must have $f = y$ a.e..  Since $y \in L^2$ we conclude that $f\in L^2$ as well.

Comment: The point is don't have convergence a priori. I mean only that the sequence is cauchy; ok, the L^p spaces are complete, but are you sure that this applies to generic measures and not only to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Sure, I am using critically that $L^2$ is complete.  If this is a sort of in-time exercise where you are supposed to prove this before you know that fact, then you would have to somehow extract that information (or have a different argument!).